# Creating a custom ActivityIndicator component in React Native that only appears after a set delay but doesn't render if action was completed

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, settimeout

I'm using React Native's ActivityIndicator to create a simple custom component that uses a boolean state hook to display it.

However, I want to add something special to it which is a delay timer for it to appear. For instance, if the API call is taking too long the ActivityIndicator activates. On the other hand, I don't want the Activity Indicator to show if the API call was executed withing the timespan of the delay.

I tried setting it up, but it isn't working as intended. The ActivityIndicator always appears after the setTimeout finishes, even after transitioning to another screen.

This is what I came up with:

```js
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, Modal } from 'react-native';
import { globalPalette } from '../../../themes';

interface Props {
  visible: boolean;
}

export const LoadingSpinner: FC<Props> = ({ visible }) => {
  const [realVisible, setRealVisible] = useState(visible);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (visible) {
      // wait for 1s before showing the spinner

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (visible) {
          setRealVisible(true);
        }
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      setRealVisible(false);
    }
  }, [visible]);

  return (
    <>
      {realVisible ? (
        <Modal animationType="fade" transparent={true} visible={realVisible}>
          <View style={styles.loaderContainer}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={globalPalette.primary} />
          </View>
        </Modal>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  loaderContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '40%',
    left: '25%',
    backgroundColor: globalPalette.white,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: '50%',
    height: '20%',
    borderColor: globalPalette.primary,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 15,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 8,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.46,
    shadowRadius: 11.14,
    elevation: 17,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the timeout if API call executed successfully by `clearTimeout`

i,e

```
let timeoutId=setTimeout(() => {
        if (visible) {
          setRealVisible(true);
        }
      }, 1000);
```

Now `clearTimeout(timeoutId)` as a calllback in you API Call.

Comment: I never imagined using clearTimeout! ... but I don't have experience using it. Is there a way to use the clearTimeout within the component in order to keep the logic as contained as possible?

Comment: yes you can use it anywhere. But you need to have timeout id with you either it is as prop or variable.